# Find the coefficient of $a^5b^5c^5d^6$ in the expansion of the following expression $(bcd+acd+abd+abc)^7$.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, binomial-theorem

Find the coefficient of $a^5b^5c^5d^6$ in the expansion of the following expression $(bcd+acd+abd+abc)^7$.
My attempt
I observe that $(bcd+acd+abd+abc)=cd(a+b)+ab(c+d)$ and this looks like the Vieta's relation for a quadratic equation. But I am not sure how to proceed. I want to avoid a bashing solution. Can any one help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Comment: For the record, the answer is $630$, but the question is of corse how to obtain that number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: In order to get a term of $a^5b^5c^5d^6$ when you expand the product, how many each of $bcd$, $acd$, $abd$, and $abc$ do you need to choose?  You might find this easier to think about if you think of each of them as adding one copy of each variable *except* for one.  Or to put it another way, you can think of the product as $((abcd)(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}))^7$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint. Note that
$$(bcd+acd+abd+abc)^7=(abcd)^7\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d}\right)^7$$
Then use the [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).